# Problem with executing bash script to execute windows VM install

Tags: linux, windows, bash, virtual-machine, qemu

Bash script

```
#!/bin/sh
WINIMG=~/vm/Win10_21H2_English_x64.iso
VIRTIMG=~/vm/virtio-win-0.1.217.iso
qemu-system-x86_64 --enable-kvm -drive driver=raw,file=~/vm/win10.img,if=virtio -m 6144 \
-net nic,model=virtio -net user -cdrom ${WINIMG} \
-drive file=${VIRTIMG},index=3,media=cdrom \
-rtc base=localtime,clock=host -smp cores=4,threads=8 \
-usb -device usb-tablet \
-net user,smb=$HOME
```

Output of run

```
qemu-system-x86_64: -drive driver=raw,file=~/vm/win10.img,if=virtio: Could not open '~/vm/win10.img': No such file or directory
```

Not sure why it responds as "No such file or directory", as i have checked all three files are there as seen below

```
loo@loo-System-Product-Name:~/Desktop/lunaLand/vm$ ls
virtio-win-0.1.217.iso  vm.sh  Win10_21H2_English_x64.iso  win10.img
```

Comment: I thing `~/Desktop/lunaLand/vm/win10.im` and `~/vm/win10.im` are not the same path values.

Answer (score 0):

The following script should resolve the "No such file or directory" error:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
WINIMG=~/Desktop/lunaLand/vm/Win10_21H2_English_x64.iso
VIRTIMG=~/Desktop/lunaLand/vm/virtio-win-0.1.217.iso
qemu-system-x86_64 --enable-kvm -drive driver=raw,file=~/Desktop/lunaLand/vm/win10.img,if=virtio -m 6144 \
-net nic,model=virtio -net user -cdrom ${WINIMG} \
-drive file=${VIRTIMG},index=3,media=cdrom \
-rtc base=localtime,clock=host -smp cores=4,threads=8 \
-usb -device usb-tablet \
-net user,smb=$HOME
```

The files are located on the desktop in the `lunaland/vm` folder and not in a `vm` folder in user loo's home directory.

Comment: Does not seem to have fixed the issue

Comment: Can you elaborate? Please give the a copy of the scripts output...